# How to export/import grant on data dictionary objects

Tags: oracle, export

I need to recreate to clone a database with expdp/impdp.
I do a full export from my source database, recreate an empty database and do a full import.
The process is doing well.

My problem:
Expdp does not export grant on data dictionary objects.
So I have many compilations errors in my new database.

Do you know the way to do it?

ps: I have all right on the two database.

my export command is

```
expdp '"/ as sysdba"' DIRECTORY=expDir FULL=Y file=full.dbf log=full.log  flashback_time=systimestamp
```

my import command is:

```
impdp '"/ as sysdba"'  DIRECTORY=expDir FILE=full.dbf FULL=Y    LOG=import.full.log partition_options=merge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve my problem with procedure dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl.
I could export grant with that in a sql file and import it in my new database

Answer (score 0):

`Grant` will be `imported` only when the `object` which actually granted is also imported. It means, the object which actually granted should also be `exported`.

For example,

If `user A granted to user B`, then, in order to get the grants imported,  you must `export/import user A too`, not just user B. And when I say user, I mean the respective objects in their schema.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it does not match to my problem. I do a full export and a full import of the database

Comment: Can you attach a log file either here or to pastebin? I'm curious what kind of sys objects are included.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `grants=y` flag in your commands.

Comment: No, this is the default parameter when you are doing a full export;)